# Test Ktor Application with Koin (not embedded)

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, ktor, koin

I'm looking to properly test a Ktor application, which uses Koin and is specifically not using the embeddedServer method of creating the app. All solutions that I have found were either outdated or were using the embedded server. Here is a simplified version of my code:

Main.kt

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = EngineMain.main(args)

fun Application.koinModule() {
    install(Koin) {
        modules(myModule)
    }
}

fun Application.doOtherStuff() {
    val someSingleton by inject<SomeSingleton>()
    (...)
}
```

application.yaml:

```yaml
ktor:
    deployment:
        port: 8080
    application:
        modules:
            - MainKt.koinModule
            - MainKt.doOtherStuff
```

My current solution does somewhat work, but feels hacky and spams `KoinNotStartedException` in the console:

Test.kt:

```kotlin
class MyTest : KoinTest {

    @AfterEach
    fun cleanup() {
        stopKoin()
    }

    @Test
    fun `mock koin module`() = testApplication {
        startKoin {
            modules(
                myModule,
                myMockModule, // override module with mocks
            )
        }
        environment {
            config = ApplicationConfig("application-test.yaml")
        }
        (...) // test code
    }
}
```

application-test.yaml

```yaml
ktor:
    deployment:
        port: 8080
    application:
        modules: # same as application.yaml, but without koin module
            - MainKt.doOtherStuff
```

If there is an intended and more importantly documented way of testing Ktor with Koin, feel free to link it.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you share a self-contained code that you want to write tests for?

Comment: Is this really relevant? I mean it could be a test for a websocket session or http endpoint or whatever. I essentially just want to replace the Koin module in those tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are starting koin inside `testApplication {}`   which already expects koin context to be up. To get ahead you should use `KoinTestRule` for junit4 or `KoinTestExtension` for junit5.

```
class MyTest : KoinTest {
    companion object {
        @JvmField
        @RegisterExtension
        val koinTestExtension = KoinTestExtension.create {
            modules(myModule, myMockModule)
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun `test`() = testApplication {
        ...
    }
}
```

More detailes in koin docs https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-test/testing

Comment: Yes, thank you, this looks indeed better. But I am not a fan of the fact, that I cannot configure each test individually, but guess I can live with that.

Comment: Oh, and I actually found the reason for the spam of errors, although the tests were working: I have a shutdown hook set up, and it triggers after all tests ran therefore running into KoinNotStartedExceptions.

Comment: @Maddin You can just declare "myModule" and then if you want to use some specific mocks, you define them for each individual test with `declareMock` function. Keep in mind that you will also need to configure it registering `MockProviderExtension`.